# Video file vs live webcam feed window size in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a python code which is opening a live web cam and I can the video feed. Below is the code:

```
import cv2

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The window which appears and show the live webcam video is quite small. But if I play a videofile using the above code, the window which appears is quite big in size. In above code I am not mentioning anything to resize the window.

**Why is this difference.?**

**How can I make the videofile window size a bit smaller.?**

Answer (score 1):

The difference is at the origin size of the images. That is saying that the image obtained by the camera is smaller than that from video file.

To make the window size smaller, you can resize the image obtained from video. The code is:

```py
ret, frame = vcap.read()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
```

For more details, you can refer to [resize](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d)

===Additional Docs===
The function imshow displays an image in the specified window. If the window was created with the cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE flag, the image is shown with its original size, however it is still limited by the screen resolution. Otherwise, the image is scaled to fit the window. 
If the window was not created before this function, as you did, it is assumed creating a window with cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE.
You can refer to [imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html), the first argument to `imshow()` is window a name. If you don't explicitly create a window with that name prior to calling `imshow()`, OpenCV will create a window with the `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` flag set, which means it will show `frame` with its original size. So if you have different frames, the window size will also be different. To get windows smaller what you can do it, create a window with `WINDOW_NORMAL` flag set, which allows you to set your window size. So you can do something like this:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Window", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# set your desired size
cv2.resizeWindow('Window', width, height)
cv2.imshow('Window', frame)
```